# Javascript DATE add AM PM

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datetime

I am doing a check of two different date times to see if one is greater than the other:

Here is my (now) current date time: Thu Aug 01 2013 10:27:40 GMT-0500 (CDT)
And here is my date time that I am seeing if it is greater or less than: Thu Aug 01 2013 12:15:00 GMT-0500 (CDT) - (that should be 12:15 am by the way)

Here is my code:

```
var current_date_time = new Date();
var date_time_checking_against = new Date(date_segment[0], date_segment[1]-1, date_segment[2], time_segment[0], time_segment[1]);
```

Which comes out to Thu Aug 01 2013 12:15:00 GMT-0500 (CDT).  And then I am doing a simple if check:

```
if(current_date_time >= date_time_checking_against){ }
```

This is not working as 10:27:40 is not after 12:15:00.  But it should be, seeing as how both times are AM.  I need to know if this is the right way, or if there is a way to change it to 24 hour format or add am pm in there somehow. Any help is greatly appreciated, let me know if you need more clarity.

Thanks!

EDIT:

Here is the date time array:

```
var date_time_str = date+' '+time;
date_time_str = date_time_str.split(' ');
["2013-08-01", "12:15", "am"] // result from split above
var date_segment = date_time_str[0].split('-');
var time_segment = date_time_str[1].split(':');
var date_time_checking_against = new Date(date_segment[0], date_segment[1]-1, date_segment[2], time_segment[0], time_segment[1]);
```

Comment: What is that "date_segment" array? What does that date look like when you log it to the console?

Comment: your second date is PM or it would be `00:15:00`

Comment: how do i add the amp pm string into the Date object?

Comment: See edit, let me know if you need more info.  I need to get am pm delegation into there

Comment: @K_G By adding 12 to the hours parameter or adding 0. An example would be: `hours + (ampm == 'pm' ? 12 : 0)`. In addition, the date object is supposed to be created with these fields (with the ones in brackets being optional): `new Date(year, month, day [hour, minute, second, millisecond]);`

Comment: Can you provide a working example please, in a bit of a time crunch, thanks!

Comment: @K_G Added it as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the following data sources, this is how you'd properly create the Date object for it...

```
date_time_str = ["2013-08-01", "12:15", "am"];
var date_segment = date_time_str[0].split('-');
var time_segment = date_time_str[1].split(':');
var date_time_checking_against = new Date(
    date_segment[0], // year
    date_segment[1]-1, // month of year
    date_segment[2], // day of month
    (time_segment[0]%12) + (date_time_str[2] == 'pm' ? 12 : 0), // hour of day
    time_segment[1]); // minute of hour
console.log(new Date() >= date_time_checking_against); // true, we've already passed this time
```